# Data Not Synchronized with SHP file

Tags: visualization, tableau-desktop

I have a problem with csv data related to the number of disease cases that will be visualized in the form of a map (shape file). The problem is as follows.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVpBJ.png)

Maybe here can help solve it. thanks